# .htaccess и переменные

Tags: .htaccess, php

Здравствуйте. Как реализовать функцию, чтобы .htaccess перенаправлял пользователя с адреса типа http://mysite.ru/var1/ на адрес http://mysite.ru/index.php?page=var1. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)\/ http://mysite.ru/index.php?page=$1 [R,L]
```

Будет перебрасывать http://mysite.ru/var1/ на http://mysite.ru/index.php?page=var1, а страницу по адресу http://mysite.ru/var2/ на http://mysite.ru/index.php?page=var2

**Обновление**

Добавь сразу после `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteRule switcher.php - [L]
```

**Обновление**

Можно так

```
RewriteRule \.\*\\.php\.* - [L] # for any .php file do nothing
```

Comment: У меня все стили и скрипты из контента документа тоже стали резаться этим кодом. ))

Comment: Появилась новая проблема, теперь все ссылки на странице приводят к индексной странице. Т.е все запросы через ajax возвращают индексную страницу

Comment: Приведите пример ссылки и опишите, как она должна работать.

Comment: Допустим, перехожу на site.ru/switcher.php?pagen=history. Он должен вернуть текст, а возвращает исходный код индексного файла.

Comment: Мне придется так каждый файл добавлять?

Answer (score 1):

[@Glorymirror](/users/18216/glorymirror), по идее, вот такая модификация поможет:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Исключает файлы из совпадения
RewriteRule (.*)\/ http://mysite.ru/index.php?page=$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect var1/ http://mysite.ru/index.php?page=var1
```

Comment: Если переменная постоянно меняется, как это будет работать?

Comment: urlrewrite используйте